# Importing values from excel into VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to pull a value from the excel sheet into VBA, use it for calculations
then export that calculated value back into a specific cell in the excel sheet?

Comment: is there an example that I could reference? I've been looking for one for about two hours and nothing I've done has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, here's how (One of many methods) The following code assumes running it from within Excel.

This gets the value

`Dim cellcontent As String
cellcontent = Worksheets("aSheet").Range("A6").Value`

And this sets it

`Worksheets("aSheet").Range("A6").Value = "foo"`

Hope this helped

Comment: Thank you! What does the range mean? I'm a little new to VBA.

Comment: The range is much like a selection if you drag your mouse in Excel, it is a "range" of cells. By providing it with only one cell however it is the same as modifying the exact cell. You can also read up on using .Cell() instead.

Comment: Using cells instead you'll need to provide 2 integers such as

`Worksheets("Mail-address").Cells(5, 6).Value = Date`

Comment: This is very helpful! I'm sorry for all the questions...but what is the "foo".

Comment: "foo" is just whatever value I was setting the contents of the cell to. You may change it to whatever you like, it is not important, it is just there as a placeholder for what you might want the cell to contain.

Answer (score 0):

Range("A6") is a way to refer to the cell in question. In this case, it's just one cell, but you could also use Range("A1:A6") to select the cells listed.